Unsure about soundness of proof about transitivity.
sorry in advance for any imprecision, missing tags etc but this is my first question.
I'm reading Daniel J. Velleman 'How To Prove It' and i'm having a hard time understanding how to write a sound proof. I encountered an exercise that i think can help me understand a lot and since there is no solution i would like your opinion.
The exercise is exrcise 19 of chapter 4.3 'More about relations'. It consists on a theorem and a proof, and the goal is understand why the proof is not correct, if the theorem is correct, and if it is give a correct proof.
The theorem is: suppose ${R}$ is a relation on $A$, and $S$ is a relation on $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ so defined: $S = \{(X, Y) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A) | \exists x \in X \exists y \in Y(xRy)\}$, if $R$ is transitive then so is $S$.
Incorrect proof:
Suppose $R$ is transitive. Suppose $(X, Y) \in S$ and $(Y, Z) \in S$. By definition of $S$, $xRy$ and $yRz$, where $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$. Since $xRy$, $yRz$ and $R$ is transitive, $xRz$. Then since $x \in X$ and $z \in Z$ it follows, by the definition of $S$, that $(X, Z)$ so $S$ is transitive. $\square$
Is the problem with this proof using an arbitrary $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ when the definition of $S$ uses '$\exists$'and not '$\forall$'? So we need to justify this elements, making the proof not wrong but unsound? Or is the problem elsewhere and the justification for the three elements is implicit?
I tried also making my proof, working on the incorrect one, and i'd like to know if it could be considered sound or not:
My proof:
Suppose $R$ relation on $A$.
Suppose $R$ is transitive, this mean three element $x$, $y$ and $z$ exist (here i instantiate the elements) so that $xRy$, $yRz$ and $xRz$.
By the definition of powerset,  $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains three set $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ so that $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$ (here i justify the use of the set $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ since $S$ is a relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)^2$).
Since $xRy$, $yRz$, $yRz$ and $x \in X$, $y \in Y$, $z \in Z$, by definition of $S$, $(X, Y) \in S$ and $(Y, Z) \in S$ but also $(X, Z) \in S$, so $S$ is transitive. $\square$
Thank you in advance.

If you only change the first $\exists$ by a $\forall$ it works however in the original case it is false. You have very easy counterexamples

@julio_es_sui_glace, you mean S ={(X,Y)∈P(A)×P(A)|∀x∈X∃y∈Y(xRy)}? that would make the theorem correct because the counterexample by mauro-allegranza in the answer would not to be considered because (Y, Z) would not be part of S, right?
,

You can directly prove it it is not hard

Sure, just wanted to be sure at least i understood what you meant. Thank you.

Yes of course, good luck then

The wrong step in the incorrect proof is: by definition of $S$: $xRy$ and $yRz$, then...
But we can only assert $xRy_1$ and $y_2Rz$ and there is no reason to assume that $y_1=y_2$.
Counterexample to the claim: use $A= \{ 1,2,3 \}$ with the usual $\lt$ relation as $R$.
And consider $X= \{ 2 \}, Y= \{ 1,3 \}$ and $Z= \{ 2 \}$, i.e. three subsets of $A$.
We have that $XSY$ because $2<3$ and $YSZ$ because $1<2$; but $XSZ$ does not hold.

Got it. I assume that step is not incorrect in my proof, since i explain where x,y and z come from, but the error then is assuming that if XSY and YSZ then XSZ forall possible subset of A?

@Luca the claim does not hold. We have a counterexample. You consider X,Y and Z such that... but when you move to the corresponding x,y,z the two y's are not the same one.

it seems obvious now. I might have to visualize more what i'm reading and trying to find counterexamples before diving in proof writing. Thank you!

@Luca you are welcome!
